# How to load local assets within a GCP cloud function?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a tiny GCP cloud function in Golang that returns a generated PNG file when calling it via HTTP. I deployed my code via ZIP-Upload in the Google Cloud Console.
Currently it gets called properly and the code gets compiled etc. But in my code I have to load several local files - a font and a .png image.
I bundled those in the ZIP I uploaded and the files are visible in the Source-View in GCP. All files (images, fonts and go-files) are within the same directory.

When calling the cloud function the log states the following:

```
2019/01/21 14:59:31 open /english.png: no such file or directory
```

I tried to change the way i build the path to the file in go. I already used /german.png statically, used several attempts to build the path dynamically.

I'm not 100 percent sure if this is the way to go, but it is my first experiment with "serverless" and i am willing to get it done the "right" way.

```
import "github.com/fogleman/gg"


func main() {
    ex, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    executableDir := filepath.Dir(ex)

    img, err :=gg.LoadPNG(path.Join(executableDir, "./english.png"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Currently the file can not be found in any attempt i made. Maybe the path the images get "deployed" into are different from the ones i tried - i have not found any note on that in the documentation.
I'd obviously expect it to be loaded properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created http functions with the following structure:

```
api
|--test.txt
|--api.go
```

And wrote simple function to reply with file content:

```
package api

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

// FileTest func
func FileTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./test.txt")
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }

    w.Write(content)
}
```

It returns the file content without any problems. https://us-central1-clickshield24m.cloudfunctions.net/api

So in your case I would try change the path to `gg.LoadPNG("./english.png")`

Comment: Mhm. I already tried that approach (as the first one), but it did not work. Strange. Will try again, thanks!

Comment: Some additional information for the next person looking it up: Looks like GCF Go 1.11 runtime function binary path is `/start` and assets/files are located in directory `/srv/files` which is also the current working directory (thus relative paths should work as pointed out in this answer). Using executable path to locate the assets is wrong because the executable is in file system root.

Comment: With go 1.13 I get "no such file or directory".

Comment: @maclir with go 1.13 my only way was by going from root up like: ./src/my_function/assets/my_asset.html

Answer (score 8):

For the Go 1.13 according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system), as of today (Jul 2020), source code is located in the `./serverless_function_source_code` directory.

A good reference to follow is the [buildpack](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/blob/master/cmd/go/functions_framework/main.go).

Answer (score 0):

`./serverless_function_source_code` didn't work for me using go113 runtime with vendoring. I wanted to locate a file in the vendor directory.

My file structure is:

```
myfn
|- main.go
|- go.mod
|- .gcloudignore
```

My deployment steps are:

```
cd myfn
go mod vendor
gcloud functions deploy MyFunction --runtime go113 --set-env-vars "PATH_FILES=./src/myfn/vendor/static"
```

I found this out by deploying a function that listed all files to a certain depth starting with `"."` and didn't see a `serverless_function_source_code` directory. But there was `src/myfn`.