# How to run an exe file in google cloud function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a windows executable file(net_audio_client.exe) on my local machine. It works fine when I run the below's python code on my pycharm IDE.

```py
def hello_world(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        print(subprocess.Popen("net_audio_client -user xxx -pass xxx -mac macaddr", shell=True,
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read())
        return f'Hello World!'
```

The same code doesn't work when I zip it and upload it to the google cloud function. I get the following errors:

```
/bin/sh: 1: net_audio_client: not found
```

The stack questions that I followed:

1. [How to load local assets within a GCP cloud function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54293314/how-to-load-local-assets-within-a-gcp-cloud-function)
2. [How to run a subprocess inside Google Cloud Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605795/how-to-run-a-subprocess-inside-google-cloud-function)

Thanks

Comment: error shows `/bin/sh` and it means it uses Linux, not Windows, so `.exe` may not work. BTW: it searchs `net_audio_client` without `.exe` and Linux treats `net_audio_client` and `net_audio_client.exe` as two different programs.

Comment: I wondering what `net_audio_client` is doing and what can mean `-mac macaddr` - if it is MAC address then it may works only in local network. On server it may use mac addressses in cloud network, not in your local network.

Comment: I have an executable file both for Linux and Windows. I have zipped them both and upload them. I had also tried uploading individual executable files.

Mac is the mac address. This is a remote hardcoded mac address. This works if I run the same program in any windows laptop with exe file in the same location. But the same doesn't work on the cloud function.

Comment: did you try to use in code `/full/path/to/net_audio_client` ? System may not know here is `net_audio_client`. If it is in the same folder as code then you may try `dot` to run program from current folder - `./net_audio_client`.

Comment: @furas I removed the .exe file and kept only Linux executable file. worked with `./net_audio_client`. thanks. I removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Functions, Cloud Run and App Engine support only Linux runtime. You can't run Windows binary on them.

You can deploy a GKE Cluster with Windows if you want to use container and your windows binary. Or directly a Compute Engine.

Comment: Right. I removed the windows exe file and replaced it with Linux binary and corrected path to `./net_audio_client`. However, it was working with `net_audio_client` on windows.

Comment: @theone1one when you run `net_audio_client` on Windows then system first searchs `net_audio_client.exe`, `net_audio_client.bat`, `net_audio_client.cmd`, etc. and next run first matching file. Windows has list of extensions which it has to check. Linux and Windows have also list of folders in which they have to search executable - Windows may have current folder on this list. Linux doesn't have it - probably for security reason - but if you add `.` to `PATH` then it will runs also programs from current folder.

Comment: If you want to run a binary in a controlled runtime environment, prefer Cloud Run to Cloud Functions.