# How to get permissions to run a binary within Google Cloud Run?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I would like to run an executable binary (GDB) within my Cloud Run container, however when I try to start the sub process, it seems I don't have permission within Cloud Run.

```
ERROR:root:[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/xtensa-esp-elf-gdb/11.2_20220823/xtensa-esp-elf-gdb/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gdb'
ERROR:root:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/main.py", line 149, in core_dump
core_parse: oto_core_dump.CoreDumpParse = oto_core_dump.parse_core_dump(core_elf.name)
File "/app/oto_core_dump.py", line 63, in parse_core_dump
gdb = EspGDB(gdb_tool, [rom_sym_cmd], core_elf_path, prog, timeout_sec=DEFAULT_GDB_TIMEOUT_SEC)
File "/app/corefile/gdb.py", line 41, in __init__
self.p = GdbController(gdb_path=gdb_path, gdb_args=gdb_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygdbmi/gdbcontroller.py", line 108, in __init__
self.spawn_new_gdb_subprocess()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygdbmi/gdbcontroller.py", line 150, in spawn_new_gdb_subprocess
bufsize=0,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/xtensa-esp-elf-gdb/11.2_20220823/xtensa-esp-elf-gdb/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gdb'
```

I've confirmed this binary works on my local Ubuntu 18.04 environment.

I've seen for example in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67600437/how-to-run-an-exe-file-in-google-cloud-function#comment119501946_67603384) that others have suggested Cloud Run as a suitable place to run a binary / executable.

(For additional context, I'm trying to automate getting info from core dump files received from an esp32 (esp-idf) by using an adapted version of their "espcoredump" tool whenever a core dump is received).

---

What I've tried:

- Started off trying to use Google Cloud Functions, could not get GDB to run there. Could not recreate the problems locally in order to see the same issues that I see in the Logs Explorer once I deployed my cloud function. Didn't have permission issues, but struggled to get the GDB sub process started.
- Switched to Google Cloud Run. Using the python:3.6.15-slim image (Python 3.6 is what ESP-IDF 4.4.5 (same version my core dump are generated with) appears to be using for their core dump / GDB analysis tool).
- I see an errno 13 (permissions denied) when my program attempts to create the GDB subprocess. Was expecting to have control over the environment enough to be able to run an executable. Starting to wonder if looking at the docker image I've chose is a good place to start looking. Do the permissions come in to play here?

---

I'm quite new to using Google Cloud and using Docker Images. Is this possible? Is there another GCP service which is more appropriate? Thank you.

Comment: The Python errors do not show problems that an executable has, for example, failure to load a library. Build the container locally and run in Docker. My guess is that your exe will  not run there either. Then figure out the problem before deploying to Cloud Run. My guess is that the exe has a dependency that is not present in your container.